# How to push data from BMC Remedy to Spring Boot application?

Tags: rest, spring-boot, jms, remedy

Let me start by saying I have ZERO remedy experience.

We need to push data from Remedy to a Spring Boot application. I have looked at many, many, many examples, but all seem to be connecting to Remedy via Java and requesting data.

I have seen code examples using Java Filter Plugin for Remedy which seems like the correct way to go.

What will be best way to implement this or maybe there is another way?

1. A Remedy Plugin(which I will develop) to call a Java RESTController in Spring Boot Application. Do I simply hardcode the RESTController URL into my code here? I know how to do this, but not sure if it is the best way.
2. Use JMS to send a message from Remedy to Spring Boot Application. We will not specify an ActiveMQ installation so Spring Boot activemq will start its own internal one. Which URL's do I use for communication?

   3. Apache Camel maybe?

So basically Remedy will send me a unique id, I will then use this ID, connect back to Remedy and retrieve more information. This I know how to do.

Sorry, but I really need some help here regarding the integration between the two and how to push data from Remedy to Spring Boot. That is actually the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider:
Create a custom runnable jar application which talks with Spring Boot app.
Then you can fire it with the Run Process filter action passing needed arguments from corresponding Remedy fields.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is still relevant, but here is my five cents worth.

There are two ways of using the Java API to send events out of Remedy:

1. An AR Filter Plugin. This will be triggerable in workflow, any time a *filter* (server side event), either triggered by a client side action (form submission, update or retrieval), or by an escalation (scheduled event). You can theoretically trigger any Java events like communication via MQ or JMS, or your REST call, but I beleive these are mostly fire and forget.
2. An ARDBC plugin. This requires you to write workflow pushing to this filter. This can either use a JDBC connection to a database, or another technology like MQ or JMS. You could in theory put a REST interface at the other end, providing the CRUD functions for the plugin. This allows communication both ways, and appears as a "normal" form for remedy workflow. There are built in functions that can be called to get the status of transactions and so on. this gives you the most flexibility.

An ARDBC plugin may be tricky to set up, but may provide the functionality you need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing this right now for a client. I didn't want another ARPlugin to build, deploy and maintain. So I use the [Springboot scheduling](https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/)

And just login and poll for data every X seconds